# Vim :redir + :execute prepends the executed command and blank lines to the output

Tags: vimscript, execute

I have the following function and command, which is supposed to save the output of a command to a scratch buffer:

```
function! ScratchCapture(cmd) abort
  echo a:cmd

  " Run and capture output in l:output
  redir => l:output
  try
    execute a:cmd
  finally
    redir END
  endtry

  " Create a new scratch buffer
  new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile

  " Put the output into the new buffer
  0put =l:output
endfunction


command! -nargs=* Capture call ScratchCapture(<q-args>)
```

Likewise, when I invoke `Capture !/bin/echo 123` I expect the new buffer to contain:

```
123
```

But in reality it contains:

```
:!/bin/echo 123^M

123
```

The `^M` is a literal ASCII `CR`, not the characters `^` and `M`.

I see a similar issue with non-`!` commands: an extra blank line is added above and below the output.

Why does the output include the executed command, and why is all the extra space being added? Can I avoid this outcome?

I get the same behavior in Neovim v0.5 (stable) and Vim 8.2.

I get the same behavior using `execute()` as well as `:execute`. Although the commenters are correct in that `execute()` is a lot easier than the `redir`/`try` dance!

---

**Update**

For anyone else trying to implement something similar, here is a Neovim-only workaround that avoids `:redir` and appears to work more or less as expected:

```
function! ScratchCapture(cmd) abort
  echo a:cmd

  " Detect if the command was a Vim command or 
  let l:cmd = substitute(a:cmd, '^\s*!', '', '')
  if a:cmd == l:cmd
    let l:output = nvim_exec(l:cmd, 1)
  else
    let l:output = system(l:cmd)
  endif

  " Create a new scratch buffer
  new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile

  " Put the output into the new buffer
  0put =l:output
endfunction


command! -nargs=* Capture call ScratchCapture(<q-args>)
```

Comment: If you're just trying to capture the output of shell commands then perhaps you can use `:h system()`. Or does it need to be more general than that?

Comment: @BLayer I would like this to generalize to _all_ commands, not just external shell commands.

Comment: Okie doke. :)  .

Comment: One hack I just thought of (in Neovim): check if the command starts with `!`. If so, use `system()`. If not, use `nvim_exec()`. But that's a Neovim-only workaround, and not an answer to the question.

Comment: No need for `nvim_exec()`. Plain `execute()` "is also great and would suffice".

Comment: What about the _function_ `execute()`? Help for `:redi[r] => {var}` says _To get the output of one command the |execute()| function can be used instead of redirection._ Don't know if that'll fare any better but worth a try.

Comment: @BLayer `execute()`, just like `:redir`, captures only regular Ex command output, not shell output. This is why regex matching might be needed to choose one of `execute()` or `system()`. However, 'tis all just fancy stuff, as one is always able to capture shell output with builtin `:h !!` that is easier to do than anything else.

Comment: @Matt `execute('foo bar')` and `execute('!foo bar')` have the same (undesirable) behavior as `:execute`.

Comment: ^ CC @BLayer, not sure if you get notified for that.

Comment: @shadowtalker Yes, as I said, execute() instead of nvim_exec().

Comment: @Matt My point is that `nvim_exec()` and `system()` do not exhibit the undesirable behavior, while `execute()`/`:execute` does. I updated the post to clarify that non-`!` commands also don't behave correctly with `execute()`/`:execute`.

Comment: What behaviour is undesirable? Blank lines and/or ^M? Just `trim()` plus `systemlist()`.

Comment: However, as I already said, there's no need in making "ultimately universal tool (tm)". Simply pressing `!!` allows to enter shell command and to grab its output into the current buffer. This is already builtin.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround ideas. I don't see why you need to be derisive about what I "need".

Comment: I just found an example where `execute()` includes other erroneous text: `"myscript.sh" 9 lines, 105 characters written`. Clearly there is some additional undocumented behavior here, and that is what I am asking about.

Comment: @shadowtalker "Erroneous" is not an accurate description of that text, fyi. The `:redir` commands redirect _messages_. Information and errors from Vim, text `:echo`ed by the user, ... most of what gets displayed in the message area. (And, for me, _not_ shell command output. Your question shows '123' being captured in the redirect var. I copied your code verbatim and I _don't_ see '123' in the new buffer! Not sure what's up with that.)

Comment: Should say  "`:redir` commands and `execute()` function" as the latter is equivalent to `redir => var | {command} | redir END` (which I learned after recommending that you give it a try :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7